# c++: TypeError at loop - but before the loop work it - (modifided)LinkedListClass iterate

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, linked-list

I had a c++ project for the arduino and i would not use the std::package for it - which also has reasons. So i look around for a LinkedList class for Arduino and i founded a class on github: https://github.com/ivanseidel/LinkedList.

I want to iterate all 's in the list.
For this I have this code:

```
uint8_t memory::write_data(uint8_t id) {
    // here is all ok -> working, but not in the loop that follows.
    uint16_t temp_size = (uint16_t) blocks->get(id);
    uint8_t blocks = (uint8_t) (temp_size / (uint8_t)255); // => 256 = 1byte - 1 => (0-255) => range (1-256);
    if (temp_size < 255) blocks++;

    uint16_t pointer = 0; // With pointer means the pointer (in byte) for the "memory(eeprom)" location 

    for (uint8_t i=0; i<id; i++) {
        Serial.print("Index:");
        Serial.println(blocks.get(i)); // -> instand of int is going to go error
        // !! ERROR: request for member 'get' in 'blocks', which is of non-class type 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}'

        //pointer += i;   
    }
    Serial.print("ALL:");
    Serial.println(pointer);
}
```

> ERROR: request for member 'get' in 'blocks', which is of non-class type 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}'

The code from library at this point is:

```
template<typename E, typename T>
T LinkedList<E, T>::get(E index){
    ListNode<T> *tmp = getNode(index);
    return (tmp ? tmp->data : T());
}
```

and ...

```
template<typename E, typename T>
ListNode<T>* LinkedList<E, T>::getNode(E index){
    int _pos = 0;
    ListNode<T>* current = root;

    // Check if the node trying to get is
    // immediatly AFTER the previous got one
    if(isCached && lastIndexGot <= index){
        _pos = lastIndexGot;
        current = lastNodeGot;
    }

    while(_pos < index && current){
        current = current->next;
        _pos++;
    }

    // Check if the object index got is the same as the required
    if(_pos == index){
        isCached = true;
        lastIndexGot = index;
        lastNodeGot = current;

        return current;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The LinkedList is defined:

```
LinkedList <uint8_t, uint16_t> *blocks = new LinkedList<uint8_t, uint16_t>();
```

I have tried to find a way out to fix this, but i can't. Can anyone tell me the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uint8_t` is simple value, not a class. It has no `.get()` method.

You simply could write
`Serial.println(blocks[i]);` if you rewrite the line

```
uint8_t blocks = (uint8_t) (temp_size / (uint8_t)255);
```

with

```
uint8_t* blocks = (uint8_t*) (temp_size / (uint8_t)255);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm so stupid. I had overrided LinkedList blocks with uint8_t blocks, I have not see this. I know not yet 100% sure with pointers from.